# По какой причине выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Делаю программу с графическим интерфейсом Tkinter. В данном окне должен находится виджет Treeview. Но по какой-то причине, если пытаюсь сделать второй уровень мне выдаёте ошибку. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Код:

```
#Таблица
self.table = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=('FIO','DB','Class','litera','adr','phone','book','aut','stat'), height=100, show='headings')

self.table.column('FIO', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
self.table.column('DB', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
self.table.column('Class', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
self.table.column('litera', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
self.table.column('phone', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
self.table.column('adr', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
self.table.column('book', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
self.table.column('aut', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
self.table.column('stat', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)

self.table.heading('FIO', text='ФИО')
self.table.heading('DB', text='День рождения')
self.table.heading('Class', text='Класс')
self.table.heading('litera', text='Литера')
self.table.heading('phone', text='Телефон')
self.table.heading('adr', text='Адрес')
self.table.heading('book', text='Книга')
self.table.heading('aut', text='Автор')
self.table.heading('stat', text='Статус')



self.table.pack()
self.table.place(x=0,y=100)

conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/LC.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
#Вывовд всех учеников
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM STUD")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    lvl1 = self.table.insert("" , tk.END , values=row)
    row1 = row[:2]
    cur.execute('SELECT BOOK, AUT, STAT FROM LC WHERE FIO=(?) and DB=(?)',row1)
    books = cur.fetchall()
    for book in books:
        self.table.insert("", lvl1, tk.END, values = book) 


#Вывод всех учителей
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TEACH")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    self.table.insert("" , tk.END , values=row)

#Вывод других посетителей
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM OTHERS_VISITERS")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    self.table.insert("" , tk.END , values=row)
```

Ошибка: _tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "I002"

Comment: Во втором уровне должны выводиться данные, которые совпадают с первыми двумя индексами row, но либо пишет что всего 2 данных из 7 используются, либо вот эта непонятная ошибка. Пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: Понял что где-то он требует целочисленный тип данных, но получает строку. Подскажите где и как исправить

Comment: Приложите весь `Traceback` ошибки. Так будет больше шансов, что кто-то захочет помочь Вам с проблемой, вместо того, чтобы разбираться, где она у Вас появляется.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, уже проблема решена. Я там накосячил с созданием второго уровня Treeview. Посмотрел видосики и тд и всё понял)

Comment: Вы можете ответить на собственный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже сам нашёл решение проблемы. Я неправильно создавал второй уровень Treeview.
Вот как должно быть: `self.table.insert(lvl1, 'end',text='Книга',values=book)`